# how to set the value of model empty on dropdown selection in view

Tags: angularjs

I'm working on a requirement in AngularJS where I need to change a div based on the dropdown selection. There are two div's basically, one contains a dropdown and another contains a textbox(both div's have the same model name city).Now, the other dropdown on whose value the div will chnage is state.

```
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4" ng-if="addressdetail.address.state == 'NewDelhi'">
                    <label for="city">
                        City
                    </label>
                    <select selectpicker="city1List" title="Select" id="City" style="" name="City" ng-model="addressdetail.address.city"
                    class="selectpicker" ng-options="obj.code as obj.desc for obj in city1List">
                        <option value="">
                        </option>
                    </select>

                </div>

                 <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4" ng-if="addressdetail.address.state != 'NewDelhi'">
                    <label for="City">                            
                                   City                            
                    </label>

                    <input id="City" style="" name="City" value="" ng-model="addressdetail.address.city" class="form-control"
                    type="text">
                </div>



                <div class="col-xs-6  col-md-4 col-sm-4 ">
                    <label for="state">
                        State
                    </label>
                    <select selectpicker="state1List" title="Select" id="State" style="" name="State" ng-model="addressdetail.address.state"
                    class="selectpicker" ng-options="obj.code as obj.desc for obj in state1List">
                        <option value="">
                        </option>
                    </select>
                </div>
```

Now everything works fine, but I don't know how to change the value of textbox to empty and dropdown to empty after the selection of the state dropdown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call angular function in `ng-change` in selection of state and make required model to empty value.

```
<select selectpicker="state1List" title="Select" id="State" style="" name="State" ng-model="addressdetail.address.state"
                    class="selectpicker" ng-options="obj.code as obj.desc for obj in state1List" 
ng-change="resetCity()">
                        <option value="">
                        </option>
                    </select>
```

Write below function in your controller.

```
$scope.resetCity = function (){
    $scope.addressdetail.address.city=YOUR_DFAULT_VALUE;
};
```

call function if any change in `<select>` of state.

Comment: @user3004356 Let me know what exactly you wants to do ?.Here you have a condition in parent div like if city is "New Delhi" then and then the child template will load in DOM.

Comment: When I select "New Delhi" in state, the city div shows a dropdown and when I select anything other than "New Delhi" in state, then it should be textbox. Now I have used ng-if and this works as wanted on dropdown selection. My question is, I want to set the value to empty as well on change irrespective of previous value. When I select New Delhi, the dropdown should have  empty value and not show previously selected value and if I select anything other than New Delhi, it should show a text box empty and not any other value

Comment: Try ng-change as I suggested.

Comment: Let me know if you don't understand or any help. Plz do accept and upvote answer if it's solved your problem.