# angular js textbox value empty when drop down change

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

if user select "text-box-value-empty", textbox should be disable and textbox should clear. i am using below code for do it. but unfortunately i could not do it.
if user enter value and select "text-box-value-empty", textbox should clear.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.myList = [{
    text: "1",
    value: "option_1"
  }, {
    text: "2",
    value: "option_2"
  },];
  $scope.sizes = "D,text-box-value-empty,";
  $scope.number = function() {
      
            
     }


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<script src="angular.js"></script>


<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 
<div>
<div ng-repeat="a in myList">
   <select ng-model="selectedOption" ng-options="choice as choice for (idx, choice) in sizes.split(',')" ng-change="number()">
   
  </select>
   
   <input type="text" ng-model="myval"/> 
</div>
</div>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: May be helpful:- [how to set the value of model empty on dropdown selection in view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29197704/how-to-set-the-value-of-model-empty-on-dropdown-selection-in-view)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, make the `selectedOption` and `myVal` as empty objects

```
$scope.myval = {}
$scope.selectedOption = {};
```

Then assign the ng-model as the property of each variables using `$index`. Also, use the `ng-disabled` to disable the input

```
<div ng-repeat="a in myList">
   <select ng-model="selectedOption[$index]" ng-options="choice as choice for (idx, choice) in sizes.split(',')" ng-change="number($index)">

  </select>

   <input ng-disabled="selectedOption[$index] == 'text-box-value-empty'" type="text" ng-model="myval[$index]"/> 
</div>
```

then pass the `index` to the `number` function and make the values empty

Demo

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.myList = [{
        text: "1",
        value: "option_1"
    }, {
        text: "2",
        value: "option_2"
    }, ];
    $scope.myval = {}
    $scope.selectedOption = {};
    $scope.sizes = "D,text-box-value-empty,";
    $scope.number = function(index) { 
        if ($scope.selectedOption[index] == 'text-box-value-empty')         {
            $scope.myval[index] = ''
        }

    }


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US"> 


<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 
<div>
<div ng-repeat="a in myList">
   <select ng-model="selectedOption[$index]" ng-options="choice as choice for (idx, choice) in sizes.split(',')" ng-change="number($index)">
   
  </select>
   
   <input ng-disabled="selectedOption[$index] == 'text-box-value-empty'" type="text" ng-model="myval[$index]"/> 
</div>
</div>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

What about

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.myList = [{
    text: "1",
    value: "option_1"
  }, {
    text: "2",
    value: "option_2"
  },];
  $scope.sizes = "D,text-box-value-empty,";
  $scope.number = function(item) {
                   item.disabled=false;
            if(item.selectedOption =='text-box-value-empty'){
                       item.myval=''
                       item.disabled=true;
                       }
                    }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 
<div>
<div ng-repeat="a in myList">
   <select ng-model="a.selectedOption" ng-options="choice as choice for (idx, choice) in sizes.split(',')" ng-change="number(a)">
  </select>
   
   <input type="text" ng-model="a.myval" ng-disabled="a.disabled"/> 
</div>
</div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be helpful to you

```js
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
         
          $scope.myList = [{
            text: "1",
            value: "option_1"
          }, {
            text: "2",
            value: "option_2"
          },];
          $scope.data=[
          {myval:"",selectedOption:0},{myval:"",selectedOption:0}
          ]
          $scope.sizes = "D,text-box-value-empty,";
         $scope.number = function(index) {
           
            if($scope.data[index].selectedOption=="text-box-value-empty")
            {
                $scope.data[index].myval="";
                    $scope.data[index].visible=false;
            
            }else{
                
                    $scope.data[index].visible=true;
            }
                  
             }


        });
```

```html
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.min.js"></script>
     
        <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 
        <div>
        <div ng-repeat="a in myList">
           <select ng-model="data[$index].selectedOption" ng-options="choice as choice for (idx, choice) in sizes.split(',')" ng-change="number($index)">
           
          </select>
           
           <input type="text" ng-model="data[$index].myval" ng-show="data[$index].visible"/> 
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```